# White Page and PHP error when accessing admin

Tags: admin, error

I receive an error in my log files when I try to access the admin panel:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getResourceId() on a non-object in /var/www/magento/includes/src/Zend_Acl.php on line 1174
```

The admin panel stays blank.
I didn't find anything about this error in Google - so it might be even something with my environment?
PHP is talking about that file:
http://www.magentodocs.org/1.7.0.2/d3/db9/lib_2_zend_2_acl_8php_source.php
But I'm not sure whether that helps me alot :-S

Any ideas on this?

Comment: In your app/etc/local.xml set `disable_local_modules` to `true`and check. If it loads fine then the issue is in one of your custom modules

Answer (score 1):

The error message originates from the `includes/src` folder which is where Magento compiles php classes.

My current guess here is that you have the Compilation Mode enabled and installed / removed / updated an extension causing the above error.

Since your admin is not available to recover from this you need to edit
`includes/config.php` and change

```
define(‘COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH’, dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.’src’);
```

to

```
#define(‘COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH’, dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.’src’);
```

Rerun the compilation process before enabling it again. To prevent this on future occasions you need to turn off compilation mode before any updates/installs and again rerunning it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've got a module that interferes with Magento Permissions/Roles/Users.

If you can't find anything, try to debug/output the $resource variable line 1173. There is theoretically a check before preventing it to be null that is failing. Give us what it contains.